# Create a second vertical menu in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For a project I am trying to create a second vertical navigation bar in Bootstrap, but I am stuck on getting the colors right. I am using the code below:

https://jsfiddle.net/pabuu1xu/

As you can see in the example, I have a second navigation bar but the background color (the background should be black) is not working. I have tried setting the background color to `background: #000 !important` or using `background-color: #000` instead of `background: #000` but so far the background remains white. Debugging using the Chrome developer tools does not give me more helpful information.

`background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);` in the hover option on the menu items is not working either, so I figure it has something to do with background settings in general.

Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong to set the background colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `right: 250px;` into `right: 0;` and change `width:0` into `width: 250px;` in `#sidebar-wrapper-right`. I believe you accidentally swopped those 2 numbers.

Comment: I believe so too, thank you! This indeed fixed my issue :-)